# Where did my insert row go? (DataGridView)

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I am using a Datagridview (unbounded mode) and I have selected "enable adding" in the designer.

when the form loads, the grid is not populated (drop down to select a supplier and button to view aliases) and there is a single row displayed with the * in the tab.

However, when I populate the grid, I no longer have this insert row for adding to the collection.

Here's basically what I am doing:

```
List<SupplierAlias> aliases = //some db lookup.
aliasGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
aliasGrid.DataSource = aliases;
```

The columns are defined as unbound columns in the designer.

Previously, I was using clearing the aliasGrid.DataBindings but I took that out and it still removes the insert row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question for others' reference.

I changed the List`<SupplierAlias`> I used to databind to a BindingList`<SupplierAlias`> and I have my insert row now.

Answer (score 0):

Does `SupplierAlias` have a public parameterless constructor? If it doesn't, you'll need to use an `IBindingList` implementation to provide the new row - for example `BindingSource`:

```
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = yourList;
    bs.AddingNew += delegate(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs args)
    {
        args.NewObject = new SomeType(args);
    };
    grid.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: It does have a public parameterless constructor which just sets its ID to a new guid.